# Validate unicode textarea for minimum length

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I have to validate Russian text (utf8) entered in textarea field of the form. The number of characters (no spaces, no empty lines) should be at least 500. The text should be checked with regex and can have many lines.

I have tried:

```
#^.{500}.*#
```

This indeed makes the restriction somehow. However, it seems that this pattern does not respect unicode. 260 Russian characters are enough to pass the check. I cannot figure out how to:

1. check unicode characters
2. do not count white spaces
3. do not count empty lines

Comment: Well, which language are you using? PHP by any chance? Not all regex engines support Unicode, and for many of them you have to activate it explicitly.

Comment: It is PHP. But it is a field in CMS that takes regular expression to check the field. If it is not possible to check unicode, it should be still possible to count without spaces and empty lines, isn't it?

Comment: try adding a `u` at the very end (after `#`). that should switch on Unicode mode. without it, `.` is very likely matching bytes not characters (I'm not sure though, whether Unicode mode will change that).

Comment: Thank you, it works with modifier u after #! Still need help to exclude spaces and new lines from counting.

Comment: @m.buettner - I don't think so, but I am not going to argue... http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: @m.buettner - Probably for most of unicode graphemes, but I don't think that for all/any...

Comment: @m.buettner - I speak 5 languages and Russian is one of them, so I know that characters used are simple, with no "character modifiers", such we can find in Arabic and some other language. Your answer works for OP, but as your solution might not work for all languages, it would be nice to use such exact wording in question and your answer as well.

Comment: @m.buettner - There are NO hard feeling at all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so firstly `.` by default matches bytes, because the input string is interpreted as ASCII. Using Unicode mode changes that (as Esailija correctly pointed out), so that `.` correctly matches (Unicode) characters:

```
#^.{500}#u
```

You don't need the trailing `.*`, because there is no need to match the full string in PHP. Note that this does not match if there is a line-break within the first 500 characters, because `.` does not match line-breaks (you should add the `s` modifier as well, to change that).

For the second requirement to exclude whitespace from the count, you could do something like this:

```
#^(?:\s*\S){500}#u
```

That subgroup matches as many space-character as possible, and then one non-space character. And that together has to be matched 500 times. Hence, you only get one repetition per one non-whitespace character, as required.

Note that there is no need for the `s` modifier for this to work in under all circumstances, because we don't use `.`.

There is one caveat though, which is explained in [this article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), though. With Unicode some characters are made up of multiple code points. For instance, `à` can be written as one character `a` followed by another code point (`U+0300` or `` ` ``) which is a combining mark. So while there are two different Unicode code points, they are still only one character. However, `.` matches code points (because it doesn't distinguish between combining marks and "stand-alone characters"). I suppose that will not affect your situation, since Cyrillic doesn't use accents. But it's something worth to be aware of. If it is relevant for you, you might want to look into a more advanced solution like Ωmega's.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Will try to understand this expression.

Comment: @Linda if you tell me which part is unclear, I can try to elaborate more on that.

Comment: `?:` only makes the subgroup non-capturing. If you leave the `?:` out the stuff that was matched with the subgroup will be saved for later reference. You don't need that later reference, so we suppress the capturing with `?:` (as an optimization... it's a good habit, using `?:` whenever possible). `\s*` then just eats up all whitespace characters that are between the current position and the next "relevant" character (so that they are not counted). then `\S` (a non-whitespace, i.e. "relevant" character is matched (but only one))... and that's what we repeat 500 times

Comment: ?: - is new for me. Will see to get this new habit ;) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need the `u` flag to activate UTF-8 awaraness in `preg_` functions:

```
$regex = '#^.{500}.*#u';
```

If you just want to see if it's 500 characters long, you can just use `mb_strlen:`

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$input_without_whitespace = preg_replace( '/[\x{0009}\x{000B}\x{000C}\x{0020}\x{00A0}\x{FEFF}\x{200C}\x{200D}]/u', "", $input );
if( mb_strlen( $input_without_whitespace ) > 500 ) {

}
```

Comment: The OP needs a regex-only solution, I think

Comment: I cannot use raw PHP. It is just a field in CMS that takes regular expression for validation. The solution of m.buettner has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex pattern

```
/(?>\s*+\P{M}\p{M}*){500}/u
```